# i need the main thread wait for the result of service that run on background

Tags: android, android-service

I have a problem in my program, when I run the program I nedd 2 iterations to update one variable called "existe".I do this update with handler.
I think is a problem of synchronization but I don't know where is it.
i have 1 broadcastreceiber that recibe the respond of the method of service, but I think first it's finishing the button handler code and later it's running the broadcastreceiber.
although I think the broadcastreceiber should run when recibe the respond of the method service? 
thanks for your help.

this is the code for button handler:

```
View.OnClickListener buttonhandler=new View.OnClickListener(){ 

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText id_camarero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_camarero);
        String numero = id_camarero.getText().toString();
        if( numero.trim().equals("")){
             AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Fallo de id");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                //.setMessage("Click salir para finalizarprograma")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Salir",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("Reintentar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();


        }
         idcamarero=Integer.parseInt(numero);
         comprobacion();
         //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyService.DATA_RECEIVED_INTENT);
        // registerReceiver(androidListener, filter);
     if((existe==false)){
         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Fallo de id");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    //.setMessage("Click salir para finalizarprograma")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Salir",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Reintentar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

     else{
    // Intent intent= new Intent(GestorRestauranteActivity.this,MenuMesas.class);
    // intent.putExtra("id", numero);//enviamos el id de camarero a la actividad que invocamos
    // startActivity(intent);
     finish();
     }
    }

};
```

this is the code of broadcastreceiber:

```
 BroadcastReceiver androidListener = new BroadcastReceiver()

{
@Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 

    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(MyService.DATA_RECEIVED_INTENT))
        {               
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.obj = intent.getExtras().get("text");

            msg.setTarget(cEmiHandler);
            msg.sendToTarget();                     
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not make it more complicated like that, simple solution is use wait(), notify() method of Object class.
In main thread, you lock an object by wait() method, in another thread (worker thread do the main job), use notify() when the job is done, main thread will be unlocked and continue.

```
Object x = new Object();
```

In main thread: x.wait();
In worker thread: do the job then x.notify();